# Custom keybinding in VSCode not working but selection from drop down menu does

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've set up `shift+enter` in VSCode to send a selected line(s) to a Python terminal. No other command is set to use `shift+enter` as its keybinding.

If I highlight some lines, right click, and select `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`, everything operates successfully. But when I try to use the specified keybinding (here `shift+enter`), the selection is disappeared by `enter`. No custom keybinding seems to send the selection to the Python terminal.

[image]

I don't understand what's causing this behavior and my knowledge of VSCode as anything other than a user is fairly limited. The custom keybinding exists in my `keybindings.json` file as

```
{
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "when": "editorFocus && !findInputFocussed && !python.datascience.ownsSelection && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The entries into keybindings.json override the VS code defaults. Try deleting your entry and it should revert to the default behaviour, which does what you're looking for.

Due to the entries in your "when" key, it looks as though you're trying to do interactive data science. If that is your goal, instead/also try:

In VS Code Settings, find and enable: 
Python > Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window

> Determines if selected code in a python file will go to the terminal or the Python interactive window when hitting shift+enter

[image: VS Code Settings: Python > Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window]